# What do we know about the death of Tyrion's High Septon?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In chapter 17 (Cersei IV) of AFFC we can read (about High Septon's death):

> No man can ask for more than to die peacefully in his sleep, full of years.

I couldn't find any more details in the book, but in the internet summaries I found two different explanations of his death.

1)

> The implication is that Qyburn killed the High Septon on Cersei's orders and that Pycelle could be next. Cersei disliked the High Septon because he was appointed by Tyrion.

[Source](http://towerofthehand.com/books/104/018/)

2)

> Queen Cersei, paranoid about what Lancel may have told him ordered his death. Osney Kettleblack snuck into the great sept and suffocated the man with a pillow while he slept.

[Source](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/High_Septon)

I was just wondering if either the first story or the second were confirmed later in the books?

Comment: Either way, Cersei had him killed. Why is the mean important?

Comment: How is that page an implication that Qyburn killed the High Septon? Osney Kettleblack confesses killing the High Septon in AFFC, which leads to Cercei's imprisonment.

Answer (score 2):

According to [his wiki page](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/High_Septon_(Tyrion%27s)):

> Cersei, paranoid of what the High Septon might know and the fact that he was selected by her brother Tyrion, has Osney Kettleblack sneak into the High Septon's chamber while he sleeps and suffocate him with a pillow.

This is confirmed in [Chapter 43 of AFFC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Feast_for_Crows-Chapter_43), when Osney:

> confesses that Cersei ordered him to kill the old High Septon

Your first source is just Qyburn making an implication. This was just him and Cersei attempting to intimidate the rest of the small council.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing has been confirmed yet. While there has been a ton of circumstantial evidence, we don't have explicit verification of this fact.

Let's start with the most obvious evidence - Ser Osney Kettleblack and his various appearances. We see 3 relevant appearances by Ser Osney:

1.In AFFC Cersei I (which precedes the death of the High Septon), Ser Osney and Ser Osfryd are commanded by Cersei to cover up Shae's presence in Tywin's bed by disposing of Shae's body. They do so obediently. At this point it is likely but not certain that Ser Osmund and Cersei have already had sex, since Osmund had turned from Tyrion to Cersei very firmly. There is no reason to believe that Ser Osney and Ser Osfryd have had sex with her, however.

2.In AFFC Cersei IV (which occurs after the death of the old High Septon), Ser Osney is promised sex in exchange for seducing Margaery. In this chapter, it is made explicit that Cersei has slept with Ser Osney exactly once in exchange for one "valiant service".

3.In AFFC Cersei X, Ser Osney, under torture, confesses to sex with Cersei and to murdering the previous High Septon.

Additionally, in ADWD Cersei I Ser Osney is referenced again, as Cersei admits to having sex with all three Kettleblacks.

This body of evidence leads to an interesting contradiction, then - either Ser Osney or Cersei must have lied in some way during their confession, unless Ser Osfryd did some off-screen work which justified being rewarded sexually for his deeds. The breakdown for potential scenarios is as follows:

1.Ser Osney murdered the old High Septon, Cersei slept with him as a reward, but she never slept with Ser Osfryd and just threw him into her confession because she was worried that Ser Osfryd might provide false testimony and she wanted to be safe. Her internal dialogue is consistent with this, and the only problem is that her internal dialogue never references murdering the old High Septon (which isn't entirely out of character for her - her mind seems very good about pushing incriminating activities out). This passes the Occam's Razor test as most likely, but means she threw Ser Osfryd under the bus HARD, which is interesting. She also doesn't mentally note that she's incriminating an innocent man, which is certainly possibly but not completely normal.

2.Ser Osney and Ser Osfryd disposed of Shae's corpse, Cersei rewarded each of them with one night of sex and later confesses to it, and Ser Osney's confession to murdering the High Septon was borne out of the impulse that a tortured man has to telling their torturer what they want to hear. Since the Faith are the ones torturing Ser Osney, it's very possible a question like, "Did Cersei have any involvement in killing the previous High Septon?" was asked. Since the Kettleblacks are not faithful individuals, it's very consistent with Ser Osney's character that he spill his guts this way under the hope of avoiding pain, throwing Cersei under the bus in hopes of saving himself.

3.Ser Osney murdered the old High Septon, Ser Osfryd did some other unmentioned task, and Cersei rewarded them both with one night of sex apiece. This seems less likely, as it seems hard to think of a service equal to "murder the pope" - but it's not out of the realm of possibility. Perhaps she slept with Ser Osfryd regularly in order to keep the captain of the Gold Cloaks loyal, but then Ser Osney would probably be less happy about being the only Kettleblack not regularly having sex with Cersei (which COULD inspire his bravado in AFFC Cersei IV, but then it is odd that he didn't bring it up). This seems like the least likely of the three options and mildly fails Occam's Razor as compared to the other two options - but it can't be said to be disproven by this, either.

Comment: You spend a lot of time talking about sex and not a lot of time answering the question. Care to [edit] your answer to make it more focused and less tangential?

Answer (score 1):

Well let's break it down.

**WARNING:** Spoilers beyond this line. You have been warned. Proceed ahead on your own hazard.

---

#### The Motive

As we all know, "Cersei is a lying whore, she's been fucking Lancel and Osmund Kettleblack and probably Moon Boy for all I know", quoting Tyrion. She was cheating on her brother with her cousin, so as you can anticipate, it had to be a secret.

But then Stannis attacked, Battle of Blackwater happened and Lancel had a near-death experience. That changed him, it made him a fanatic/pious man, choose your word. He wanted forgiveness for his sins, so badly. And the idiot told about his change to Cersei:

> Lancel nodded, plainly miserable. "When it seemed that I might die,
> **my father brought the High Septon to pray for me. He is a good man**." Her cousin's eyes were wet and shiny, a child's eyes in an old
> man's face. "**He says the Mother spared me for some holy purpose, so
> I might atone for my sins**."
>
> Cersei wondered how he intended to atone for her. Knighting him was a
> mistake, and bedding him a bigger one. Lancel was a weak reed, and she
> liked his newfound piety not at all; he had been much more amusing
> when he was trying to be Jaime. **What has this mewling fool told the
> High Septon? And what will he tell his little Frey when they lie
> together in the dark?** If he confessed to bedding Cersei, well, she
> could weather that. Men were always lying about women; she would put
> it down as the braggadocio of a callow boy smitten by her beauty. **If
> he sings of Robert and the strongwine**, though . . . **"Atonement is
> best achieved through prayer," Cersei told him. "Silent prayer."** She
> left him to think about that and girded herself to face the Tyrell
> host.
> <sub>***AFFC - Cersei II***</sub>

So there you have it, Cersei feared that Lancel might expose her role in Robert's murder for the whole realm to see. She wasn't sure if he actually told the High Septon about that particular sin, but better safe than sorry eh?

#### Cersei's swift actions

Cersei didn't like the way the High Septon looked at her after her father was murdered. She couldn't be sure if it was a knowing smile or a threatening smile, which are the same anyways. And then it occurred to her, that this man was appointed by the Imp, what if he is in league with him?

> This one... This High Septon was of Tyrion’s making, Cersei recalled
> suddenly. It was a disquieting thought.
>
> The old man’s spotted hand looked like a chicken claw as it poked from
> a sleeve encrusted with golden scrollwork and small crystals. Cersei
> knelt on the wet marble and kissed his fingers, and bid Tommen to do
> the same. **What does he know of me? How much did the dwarf tell him?
> The High Septon smiled as he escorted her into the sept. But was it a
> threatening smile full of unspoken knowledge, or just some vacuous
> twitch of an old man’s wrinkled lips?** The queen could not be
> certain.
> <sub>***AFFC - Cersei II***</sub>

She knew Tyrion to be her mortal enemy and if this man was his creature, she could never sleep easy until she took care of him. And of course, there was a little problem named Lancel. Cersei pre-empted her *enemies* before they could trap her.

#### The Deed

The High Septon died in his sleep apparently.

> Qyburn had reminded her of that, the clever man. “Our late High Septon
> let too much pass, I fear. Age had dimmed his sight and sapped his
> strength.”
>
> “He was an old done man, Your Grace.” Qyburn smiled at Pycelle. “**His
> passing should not have surprised us. No man can ask for more than to
> die peacefully in his sleep, full of years.**”
> <sub>***AFFC - Cersei IV***</sub>

Now note how Qyburn passed a smile to Pycelle while talking about old men dying in their sleep. Is he next to die peacefully in his sleep? But Why Pycelle? Ah, well Pycelle knows about the incest and murder of Jon Arryn as well. Maybe it was time to purge the court and Cersei already stated that she wanted sweep the court clean and surround Tommen with her own people.

And that was the end of it. Everyone thought the High Septon died naturally. Cersei's plan was successful, even the readers weren't aware what had happened.

That is until, Cersei acted on her second plan, to get rid of Margaery Tyrell. She sent Osney Kettleblack to bear false witness against her but things backfired when Osney accused her instead, not just of adultery but also of murdering the High Septon.

> He is just a priest, he cannot do this. “It is not for the Faith to
> condemn a man to death, whatever his offense.”
>
> “Whatever his offense.” The High Septon repeated the words slowly,
> weighing them. “Strange to say, Your Grace, **the more diligently we
> applied the scourge, the more Ser Osney’s offenses seemed to change.
> He would now have us believe that he never touched Margaery Tyrell**.
> Is that not so, Ser Osney?”
>
> Osney Kettleblack opened his eyes. When he saw the queen standing
> there before him he ran his tongue across his swollen lips, and said,
> “The Wall. You promised me the Wall.”
>
> “He is mad,” said Cersei. “You have driven him mad.”
>
> “Ser Osney,” said the High Septon, in a firm, clear voice, “**did you
> have carnal knowledge of the queen**?”
>
> “Aye.” The chains rattled softly as Osney twisted in his shackles.
> “**That one there. She’s the queen I fucked, the one sent me to kill
> the old High Septon.** He never had no guards. I just come in when he
> was sleeping and pushed a pillow down across his face.”
> <sub>***AFFC - Cersei X***</sub>

#### So did Lancel spill the beans?

Yes, yes he did. He confessed as much in front of Jaime. He confessed murdering Robert and bedding the Queen. And he also admitted that he told the High Septon everything.

> “Do not think ill of the queen,” Lancel pleaded. “All flesh is weak,
> Jaime. No harm came of our sin. No... no bastard.”
>
> “No. Bastards are seldom made upon the belly.” He wondered what his
> cousin would say if he were to confess his own sins, the three
> treasons Cersei had named Joffrey, Tommen, and Myrcella.
>
> “**I was angry with Her Grace after the battle, but the High Septon
> said I must forgive her.**”
>
> “You confessed your sins to His High Holiness, did you?”
>
> “He prayed for me when I was wounded. He was a good man.”
>
> **He’s a dead man**. They rang the bells for him. He wondered if his cousin had any notion what fruit his words had borne. “Lancel, you’re
> a bloody fool.”
> <sub>***AFFC - Jaime IV***</sub>

It is unclear whether Lancel realized what he had done but Jaime at once knew that this was why the High Septon died so suddenly.

So yes, our green-eyed lioness was right all along.

---

#### Conclusion

So in conclusion:

1. Cersei was already wary about what Lancel might have told the High Septon. She didn't care about him boasting on bedding her, Robert's murder was however another story.
2. Cersei was further disposed against the High Septon once Tyrion slew her father. Cersei had grown paranoid and she was seeing Tyrion's hand in everything those days.
3. It was Osney Kettleblack, not Qyburn, who smothered the High Septon to death.